# Android: Adding exsting contacts as favourite contact?

Tags: android, android-contacts

I have one ListView in which i am getting all contacts of phone. in ListView  i have put the one button and on clicking on that button that contact should be added in favourites and on clicking again that should be removed from favourites.
 Here i found the code to add new contact with favourite tag.but how to do this on clicking on button.i have tried with this code:

**Code:**

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
        int rawContactInsertIndex = ops.size();

        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
                .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null)
                .withValue(RawContacts.STARRED, true).build());
        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                .newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID,
                        rawContactInsertIndex)
                .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(Phone.NUMBER, "91-0000000002").build());
        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                .newUpdate(Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID,
                        rawContactInsertIndex)
                .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, "Maulik patel").build());
```

Using this code all contacts are added to the favourite
thanks

Comment: You're also attempting to add a phone number and change the display name - but, since the initial op is an update these are (thankfully) failing. Start by changing your `newUpdate(..)` to `ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContentUris.withAppendedId(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, idOfTheRawContactYouWantToUpdate))` and remove all that extra crap.

Comment: thanks for your reply but can you be more specific about the id. how can i get particular id of clicked contact?

Comment: You're apparently listing them somehow. The value of the `RawContact._ID` column is the one you in your `UPDATE` operation.

Comment: I am getting null pointer exception when I do getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops); Could you please help me?

Comment: hey @juned...hav u solved this problem??

Comment: Hey @ArunaRajput please see my answer

Comment: ok @juned that code is on button clicked??

Comment: how to remove and add number from the favorite list?? @juned

Comment: @ArunaRajput just change the 1 to 0 to make it unfavorite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here what is finally work for me to favourite specific contact.

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        String[] fv = new String[] { "juned" };
        values.put(Contacts.STARRED, 1);
        getContentResolver().update(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, values,
                Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + "= ?", fv);
```

just change the 1 to 0 for unfavorite.

Comment: I am getting the expetion, java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: URI: content://contacts, calling user: com.example.newapp, calling package:com.example.newapp. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

I needed to add/remove to favourites contact with specific contact ID instead of contact name so I've modified juned's code and here it is:

```
int contactId = 10;    // some contact's ID

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(ContactsContract.Contacts.STARRED, 1);
getActivity().getContentResolver().update(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, values,
    ContactsContract.Contacts._ID + "= ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(contactId) });
```

The difference is you just change the `DISPLAY_NAME` to `_ID`.